# Object-Object Mapping in javascript

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

Based on an `array` of keys, is there any way to map one `object` with another `object`?

```
var obj1 = { 'firstName': 'Tom', 'lastName': 'Hardy', 'age': 32 };
var obj2 = { 'firstName': 'Jon', 'lastName': 'Snow', 'age': 33 };
keys = ['lastName', 'age'];
```

I want to update the value of `lastName` and `age` of  `obj1`'s by the `obj2`'s value.

Is there any `lodash` function available for this type of mapping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With pure Javascript you can do it using [**Array#forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function to iterate over the keys and use `[]` notation to access the properties based on other variable's value.

```js
var obj1 = { 'firstName': 'Tom', 'lastName': 'Hardy', 'age': 32 };
var obj2 = { 'firstName': 'Jon', 'lastName': 'Snow', 'age': 33 };
var keys = ['lastName', 'age'];

keys.forEach(prop => obj1[prop] = obj2[prop]);

console.log(obj1);
```

With [**lodash#forEach**](https://lodash.com/docs/#forEach)

```js
var obj1 = { 'firstName': 'Tom', 'lastName': 'Hardy', 'age': 32 };
var obj2 = { 'firstName': 'Jon', 'lastName': 'Snow', 'age': 33 };
var keys = ['lastName', 'age'];

_.forEach(keys, prop => obj1[prop] = obj2[prop]);

console.log(obj1);
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js'></script>
```

Comment: is there any lodash/underscore.js mapper available for this type of mapping

Comment: `lodash` is just a library, and it also have a function https://lodash.com/docs/#forEach with that you can do the same

Comment: @URoy - Why would you bother with Lodash or Underscore when it is only 46 characters of plain JS? (And it could even be < 40 using `p` instead of `prop`.)

Comment: @nnnnnn I don't like one characters variables :)

Comment: Meaningful variable names are good, but in a tiny arrow function like this it would be pretty obvious what `p` meant - but that suggestion was just for the OP if they were looking for maximum brevity. Regarding your Lodash suggestion, I think the OP was looking for a hypothetical `_.mapProperties()` type function that automatically does this for properties listed in an array, not just an alternative implementation of `forEach`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`lodash#assign`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#assign) and [`lodash#pick`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#assign) to achieve this result.

```
_.assign(obj1, _.pick(obj2, keys));
```

```js
var obj1 = { 'firstName': 'Tom', 'lastName': 'Hardy', 'age': 32 };
var obj2 = { 'firstName': 'Jon', 'lastName': 'Snow', 'age': 33 };
var keys = ['lastName', 'age'];

_.assign(obj1, _.pick(obj2, keys));

console.log(obj1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;top:0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Alternatively, here's an immutable solution using [`lodash#pick`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#pick) and [`lodash#defaults`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#defaults):

```
var result = _(obj2).pick(keys).defaults(obj1);
```

```js
var obj1 = { 'firstName': 'Tom', 'lastName': 'Hardy', 'age': 32 };
var obj2 = { 'firstName': 'Jon', 'lastName': 'Snow', 'age': 33 };
var keys = ['lastName', 'age'];

var result = _(obj2).pick(keys).defaults(obj1);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;top:0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```